# Is it possible to replace a string in a model instance field based on field original value

Tags: django, django-queryset

I need to replace a field value based on current value such that:

```
Current:Replacement
S:D
D:S
s:d
d:s
```

I can do it using multiple queries:

```
myModel.objects.filter(child = ID).update(rel = Replace('rel', Value('S'), Value('D')))
myModel.objects.filter(child = ID).update(rel = Replace('rel', Value('D'), Value('S')))
myModel.objects.filter(child = ID).update(rel = Replace('rel', Value('s'), Value('d')))
myModel.objects.filter(child = ID).update(rel = Replace('rel', Value('d'), Value('s')))
```

However, that would require multiple database hits and only one query will match. I tried to use a hash table in the update query but I got error:

```
nr = {'S':'D', 's':'d', 'D':'S', 'd':'s'}
myModel.objects.filter(child = ID).update(rel = Replace('rel', F('rel'), nr[F('rel')]))
KeyError: F(rel)
```

I recoded my answer to solve the double replacement issue but still the database gets hit four times:

```
myModel.objects.filter(child = ID, rel = 'D').update(rel = Value('S'))
myModel.objects.filter(child = ID, rel = 'd').update(rel = Value('s'))
myModel.objects.filter(child = ID, rel = 'S').update(rel = Value('D'))
myModel.objects.filter(child = ID, rel = 's').update(rel = Value('d'))
```

Comment: You can not subscript, since Django converts this to an SQL query, and you thus can not use Python expressions. Using multiple queries will not work effectively either, since you replace `S` with `D` but then back to `S`.

Comment: Thanks for quick answer. Yes; I was not aware of the double replacement issue! my suggestion will not work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Fortunately; I found a solution to my question  using Django Conditional Expressions and Conditional update:

```
myModel.objects.filter(child=ID).update(opprel=Case(
When(opprel='D',then=Value('S')),
When(opprel='d',then=Value('s')),
When(opprel='S',then=Value('D')),
When(opprel='s',then=Value('d')),
default=F('opprel')
)))
```